# Call a method on a Class object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, record

My task is to add a class method to the `Profile` class, called `get_all_profiles`, which:

- accepts a min and max for the birth year
- issues a `BETWEEN` SQL clause in a `WHERE` clause to locate `Profile`s with birth years that are between min year and max year
- defends itself against SQL injection when applying the parameters to
  the SQL clauses
- returns a collection of Profiles in ASC birth year order

I think the implementation below is correct, but how I can call it on the class object (i.e. `Profile.get_all_profiles?(min, max)`)?

```
def get_all_profiles(start_year, end_year)
  Profile.where(:birth_year => start_year..end_year).order(:birth_year )
end
```

Comment: There was like the exact same question a while ago

Comment: You missed a crucial part where they said add a **class** method. You must define it as `def self.get_all_profiles(start_year, end_year)` then you can call it like `Profile.get_all_profiles(...)`. Make sure you read your lecture notes about the difference between instance methods and class methods.

Answer (score 0):

To implement this as a class method you can write the above method as:

```
def self.get_all_profiles(start_year, end_year)
  Profile.where(:birth_year => start_year..end_year).order(:birth_year )
end
```

or,

```
class << self

  def get_all_profiles(start_year, end_year)
    Profile.where(:birth_year => start_year..end_year).order(:birth_year )
  end

  ... other class methods ...

end
```

So you'll be able to call it as:

```
Profile.get_all_profiles(start_year, end_year)
```

Comment: Thank you for all replies  def self.get_all_profiles(start_year, end_year)
     where(birth_year: start_year..end_year).order(:birth_year )
       end  working for me